# Important Subgroups of Arithmetical Functions

Tags: group-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I am taking a course in Analytic Number Theory. The main object of study is arithmetical functions. Moreover, if we look at the arithmetical functions which do not vanish at $1$, then they form a group under Dirichlet multiplication, $*$. An important subgroup of this group is the group of multiplicative functions. My question is: Is there other important subgroups of this group? What do we know about these groups? Is there any "famous" group among these subgroups?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Arithmetic functions form a **ring** $(D,+,\ast)$ under addition $(f+g)(n)=f(n)+g(n)$ and Dirichlet convolution $f\ast g$, but $(R,\ast)$ is *not* a group. Rather we have the group of units $U(D)$. Note that $D$ is a UFD. The group $U(D)$ has been studied, see the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/why-prove-that-multiplicative-functions-are-a-group-with-dirichlet-convolution?rq=1).

Comment: The group of units $U(D)$ consists of the arithmetic functions $f$ with $f(1)\neq 0$. A reference given above is James Delaney's paper on this group (and its subgroups).